# Count Object in Models Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a problem with creating a modelfield which Count number of people who like an article.
I have class Like:

```
class Reaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    article = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

and class Article:

```
from api.reactions.models import Reaction
class Article(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post = models.TextField()
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post

    def calculate_likes(self):
        likes = Reaction.objects.count(article=self.pk)
        self.likes = likes
        self.save()
        return self.likes
```

But likes wont be counted.
What's wrong with this? Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: what is pk here at 4th last line ?

Comment: article id, @Doda

Comment: No relationship between Article and Reaction???

Comment: In this line: article = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), I use IntegerField to return article ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_likes(self):
        return self.likes.all().count()
```

this should basically be it, you don't need to point a model to an instance of itself, creating a reaction class is overkill.
But if you are still going for it instead of:

```
likes = Reaction.objects.count(article=self.pk)
```

Try:

```
likes = Reaction.objects.filter(article=self.pk).count()
```

Comment: I try all your 3 solutions but it's not work. Use def is not return count. Solution 2 and 3, it came to error: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: u can try 'likes = Reaction.objects.filter(article__1contains=self.id).count()'